# Winning outfits instead of buying them

Tags: pc, guild-wars-2

Are there any outfits that are winnable into the game, instead of available into the shop ?

Comment: First thing to do when you have a question like this should always be to consult the wiki. In this case, the [Outfit](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Outfit) page tells you that: "The Hexed Outfit, Common Clothing Outfit and other clothing outfits are the only outfits available outside of the Gem Store. Clothing outfits tonics found on the trading post may be exchanged for respective outfits at the Black Lion Trader (Merchant) at the Black Lion Trading Company HQ." There are also historical ones you can no longer get (I have one or two but never bought anything from the gem store).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, none of the existing outfits can be obtained through a normal loot, quest or anything. The closest option that could exist would be to loot a [Black Lion Chest Key](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest_Key), to open a [Black Lion Chest](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest) and to be lucky enough to directly get an outfit or to get a [Guaranteed Wardrobe Unlock](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guaranteed_Wardrobe_Unlock)  and to get an outfit from it.